# yiiphp framework - input data on website and execute command on server

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a site that runs yii php frame work. I am not a coder and need some help with some needed code for the front end and back end that will allow my users to enter 3 parts of information; wallet address, coin symbol (coin symbol must be entered or converted to CAPS) and algorithm (algorithm will need to be a drop down box so that the proper format is given).

The text area for this section can read something like, " Wrong blocks associated to your wallet? Submit the following information: "

Once they enter that information and then hit the submit button, on the server the following command is ran;

```
yiimp user swap <address> <symbol>
```

followed by

```
screen -X -S <algo> quit
STRATUM_DIR=/var/stratum
screen -dmS <algo> $STRATUM_DIR/run.sh <algo>
```

this is part of an opensource project and the specific file that this needs to be a part of can be seen here

[yiimp wallet.php](https://github.com/tpruvot/yiimp/blob/next/web/yaamp/modules/site/wallet.php)

Answer (score 0):

To edit Yiimp frontend you need to go to this folder, there it contains all frontend files

```
/var/web/yaamp/modules/site/
```